# Haxe -> JS switch statement branches wrong (Haxe -> Flash of same code works fine), why?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, switch-statement, haxe

I've been unable to reproduce this in complete isolation, but here's an actual screenshot of some Haxe code in my project:

[image: code listing with line numbers]

I would say that if line 567 outputs "true" as its last value, then the next trace should have "right", not "wrong".  When I transpile to Flash (using haxe 3.2.1), that's how it is.  However, transpiling to html5, I get this in the console of Firefox or Chrome:

```
State_Play.hx:567: fairy_destination,true
State_Play.hx:572: wrong,fairy_destination,true
```

My question: **how can this be?**

The JS code produced seems sensible enough:

```
haxe_Log.trace(this._ui.get_currMode(),{ fileName : "State_Play.hx", lineNumber : 567, className : "State_Play", methodName : "clickMap", customParams : [this._ui.get_currMode() == "fairy_destination"]});
var _g2 = this._ui.get_currMode();
switch(_g2) {
case "fairy_destination":
    haxe_Log.trace("right",{ fileName : "State_Play.hx", lineNumber : 570, className : "State_Play", methodName : "clickMap", customParams : [this._ui.get_currMode(),this._ui.get_currMode() == "fairy_destination"]});
    break;
default:
    haxe_Log.trace("wrong",{ fileName : "State_Play.hx", lineNumber : 572, className : "State_Play", methodName : "clickMap", customParams : [this._ui.get_currMode(),this._ui.get_currMode() == "fairy_destination"]});
}
```

Comment: Show us what you get from sequential invocations of currMode.
Something like:
trace(_ui.currMode);
trace(_ui.currMode);
trace(_ui.currMode);

Comment: @RealyUniqueName As I said, I still get "true" output evaluating the pre-switch trace (therefore it must equal `"fairy_destination"`; although I've also done it directly to verify this myself before, too.)  I just didn't feel like redoing the screenshot, but I guess I will for clarity...

Comment: @RealyUniqueName There, updated for clarity (if a bit less brevity.)

Comment: This looks like a bug? You can report them at github and link to this post. https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues

Comment: @MarkKnol I thought so too, but I'm unable to reproduce it in absolute isolation, which usually (generally for bug reports) means the issue simply gets closed.  I guess I will eventually try but I thought I would ask here first in case somebody could spot something that I was missing in my understanding of the situation.

Comment: @Kev, after you declare `var _g2 = this._ui.get_currMode();` what does `haxe_Log.trace("_g2 is : ", _g2);` say about it? If it doesn't confirm "fairy_destination" then likely why it auto defaults to "wrong" status...

Comment: @VC.One I edited the output JS manually to try that.  It does confirm "fairy_destination."  (Also, I have tried at the Haxe level making my own temporary variable to give to `switch`, and tracing that variable in the case statements.  Same result.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you really need to create a test that fails using 
http://try.haxe.org/
then it will be much easier to help.

Comment: I know, and I've tried.  That's the darned thing about it, I can't reproduce it in isolation, as I said in the OP.  Well, that and the JS itself seems to misbehave, doesn't it?